# option value from database in edit php

Tags: php, mysql

How to get value of option on edit case my code is given below: code i here in PHP.

```
    <?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") Or die('not connected');
    mysql_select_db("studyagain",$con);


    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if($_GET["id"]){
        $updateid=$_GET["id"];
    }

    $query="select * from student where id='$updateid' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <table> 
    <tr>
    <td>
        First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row["name"];?>">
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Last Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row["lname"];?>">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        //here i want the option value in edit mode
Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="age" >
            <option >Select Age</option>
        <?php $getoptions = agedropdown(); ?>
        <?php foreach ($getoptions as $key => $value) { ?>

                    <option><?= $value ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        College:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="collg" value="<?php echo $row["collgname"];?>">
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    City:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $row["city"];?>">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="sub">
        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $age=$_POST['age'];
        $collg=$_POST['collg'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];

    $query="insert into student set name='$fname',lname='$lname',age='$age',collgname='$collg',city='$city'";
    if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo "Data Inserted";
    }
    else{
        echo "Data Not inserted".mysql_error();
    }
    }


    ?>





    <?php

    function agedropdown(){

        $range=range(1,110);
        foreach ($range as  $value) {

        }
        return $range;
    }

    ?>

            it is the code i want option default value on edit from database not getting value on edit mode in select box age is not get selected on edit mode.so pls help me regarding this..


            my db table Is:

            CREATE TABLE `student` (
              `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              `lname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              `age` int(20) NOT NULL,
              `collgname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
              `city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

    data in table is given below:

        | id | name   | lname  | age | collgname | city  |
        +----+--------+--------+-----+-----------+-------+
        |  1 | Gaurav | pandey |  11 raj      | nepal |
        +----+--------+--------+-----+-----------+-------+
         data i have in table is
```

i want this age=11 when i m going to edit the data .. on select box presently m getting all value in edit mode bt select option value not comes in edit mode so pls help me related this.not getting value on select box on edit .

Comment: mysql is depreciated, use mysqli. Also, learn AJAX.

Comment: i jst need value in option value on edited case how cud it related to the mysql or mysqli

Comment: really hard to understand what you mean/want, and code is almost a mess... you should order the code in a manner we can see (fast & easy) what you try to achieve, then 1/ use error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); on top on your page, then think about using prepared statements. If you get error message, or warning, then give use a hint

Comment: simply i want option value in select box on update time.. m not getting value

Comment: as I told you before, unfortunately (and I don't mean to be rude), the code you posted here is a mess. [EXAMPLE](https://pastebin.com/5uz95G5B) is working, and there's not much difference with yours, so think about what was asked before : how is your code organized ? in which order does it run ? any error ?

Answer (score 1):

as someone would say "asking for details shouldn't be like pulling teeth"
and as @Gaurav-Pandey is not getting involved anymore, this is my last contribution :)

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$my_age = "11"; /* set it up from wherever it comes from as you need it */

function agedropdown(){

        $range=range(1,25);
        foreach ($range as  $value) {

        }
        return $range;
    }

echo"<select name=\"age\">";
echo"<option>Select Age</option>";
$getoptions = agedropdown();

foreach ($getoptions as $key => $value) {
        if($value == $my_age) { $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ""; }
         echo"<option value=\"$value\" $selected>$value</option>";
        }
echo"</select>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same database like yours and working. Try this in your case..

```
   $result=mysql_query($query);
   $total=count($result); 
   for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++);
   ?> 
   <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <table> <tr> <td>
    First Name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row[0]['name'];?>"> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>
    Last Name:&nbsp; <input type="text" name="lname"   value="<?php echo $row[0]['lname'];?>">   </td> </tr> <tr> <td>
    Age:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name="age" >
    <option >Select Age</option> <?php echo $row[0]['age']</option> <?php } ?> </select> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>College:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="collg" value="<?php echo $row[0]['collgname'];?>"> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>City:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $row[0]['city'];?>"> </td> </tr> <tr> <td> <input type="submit" name="sub"> </td> </tr> </table> </form> </body> </html>
```

Comment: this line might give you a weird 'select' though, not sure it'll match his needs... -> <option >Select Age</option> <?php echo $row[0]['age']</option>

Comment: Not a clear question for understanding the needs but i guess that he want age that fetched from database. Look at the question he want `age:11` here and database have same.

Comment: no, he wants age from 1->110 if his function has no mistake -> $range=range(1,110); EDIT : please, don't post an answer if you don't clearly understand the problem. EDIT 2 : if he gets the proper 'select', he might want the user age to be selected, that's another issue...

Comment: I think he want selected age `11` and not want to set age everytime when he update other fields.